# How to get all the information of a uniswap trade using web3?

Tags: solidity, web3js, etherscan, web3.py

I would like (if possible) to read the exact trade made in a transaction where and address interact with Uniswap (or other DEX) using web3.

Using Etherscan is quite simple to read the tokens swapped in a transaction, see for example
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x28dc4fd2364440a60a2e027de0f9b3d77cb1420ecd8662637224e5f5ecb9695a in transaction action.

My final purpose would be that for a given transaction extract the same information.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I made a Python function to do exactly this: https://smart-contracts-for-testing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uniswap_analysis.html#smart_contracts_for_testing.uniswap_v2_analysis.analyse_trade

Answer (score 0):

You can get a transaction by it's hash via calling `getTransaction`. The returned object contains all the details you see in block explorers like Etherscan.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum transaction contains

- input (call data)
- output (receipts)

Both need to be analysed to underthe Uniswap trades fully. [web3-ethereum-defi package provides function uniswap_v3.analyse_trade_by_hash()](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/_autosummary_uniswap_v2/eth_defi.uniswap_v2.analysis.analyse_trade_by_hash.html#eth_defi.uniswap_v2.analysis.analyse_trade_by_hash) that decodes the transaction for you.